# mailx does not allow piping body text AND specifying a file attachment at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, mailx

I am trying to set up an automized sending of notification mails at certain events.
I want to pass a message body and attach a seperate log file.

I can pass the body text with the following command:

```
mymessage="test message\nwhatever\n"
echo -e "$mymessage"| mailx -s "testmail" -r "sender@mymail.de" "recepient@mymail.de"
```

In that case I get an email with my message in the body

Now if I want to add a log file as an attachment, all tutorials i could find as well as the mailx help function imply i should simply use the "-A" (for attachment) argument

```
mymessage="test message\nwhatever\n"
echo -e "$mymessage"| mailx -A /home/me/myattachment.txt -s "testmail" -r "sender@mymail.de" "recepient@mymail.de"
```

However, if I do that, my body text is simply ignored (and in case my attachment is a text file, it is used as attachment AND body text at the same time).

I guess this has something to do with the fact that there are different versions of mailx out there, that all work differently? My version is "mailx (GNU Mailutils) 3.4", installed from the standard repository of the most recent ubuntu server edition using `sudo apt install mailutils`.

How can I specify a body text seperately from an attachment?

EDIT: please note that there seem to be different versions of mailx that seem to work as the tutorials imply. In many versions there is a "-a" option instead of my "-A". my versions does not have this option. Yet my version is the one that is installed from standard repositories in ubuntu when installing maulutils. How do I get the other versions?

Comment: Sure it does. The correct option is `-a file  Attach the given file to the message.` NOT `-A name  Executes an account command (see below) for name after the startup files have been read.`

Comment: Well that is exatcly the problem that i stated above. There are apparently different versions of mailx. In your version (and that of many tutorials) "-a" is for attachments. In my version "-A" is for attachments, while "-a" is for specifying headers. Here what i get when i use "-a" instead of "-A": ```mailx: Invalid header: /home/me/myattachment.txt' ' '

Comment: This is driving me crazy, since this is the mailutils from the ubuntu repository, yet apparently EVERYBODY else has a totally different version with different arguments?

Comment: All versions are forks from the original Berkeley mailx. The one that remains in current development is `S-nail`, see, e.g. [S-nail - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S-nail). If you are using one with the `-A` option for attachment, it is likely been out of development for more than a decade. Check the package that your `mailx` comes from (likely either `Berkeley mail`, `heirloom-mailx`, or some other variant) Whatever it is, I'd remove it and install `s-nail` or at least `heirloom-mailx` -- both support `-a` attachemnt.

Comment: O bother, so mailutils was simply the wrong (outdated) package? But that was what was suggested when trying to run mailx on my system. So i should uninstall mailutils and install s-nail instead?

Comment: YES! -- Life will be much easier `:)` I also wouldn't be surprised if the howto that recommends mailutils wasn't from 2005 or earlier -- all the original howtos are getting a bit long in the tooth by now....

Comment: aaargh, I just did: "sudo apt install s-nail", but now there is no "mailx" to be found? should i have installed "bsd-mailx" instead? And what is that outdated mailutils doing in the repositories in the first place?

Comment: It's just a symlink to `mail`. So `su` and then `cd /usr/bin` and `ln -s mail mailx`. Or just use `mail` instead of `mailx` `:)`

Comment: apparantly not: after installing s-nail there is also no mail. Neither mail nor mailx. nothing... tyring to run mail gives me "Command 'mail' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install mailutils" (which is the above mentioned "outdated" version). Installing bsd-mailx gives me the same usage/version as mailutils. can't find a heirloom-mailx version. Forums say that version has been removed from ubuntu repositories. I am freaking out a little...

Comment: This link shows an issue with s-nail showing that it does not include mail or mailx. apparently this was never resolved? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858080

Comment: No, it is a problem with how your distro builds it. Building with `VAL_MAILX=mail` and `VAL_MAIL=/var/spool/mail` is all that is needed for `s-nail` to provide `mail` and hence `mailx`. Right now I am running `mailx --version` results in `mail v14.9.17, 2020-02-01 (built for Linux)`  (oops -- sorry for the late reply -- I see you got it! Good deal)

Answer (score 1):

OK found it, 
apparently s-nail completely replaces mail AND mailx? In the other peoples Ubuntu versions "mail" and "mailx" are apparently mostly simply symlinks to s-nail, and the most current version simply does not create these symlinks? 
In any case, I just had to replace the "mail" or "mailx" with "s-nail" to get the same functionality and argument options as described in all of the turotials for mailx...
Thanks to David C. Rankin for putting me on the correct track here, as i could not find this explicitely described anywhere...